# Qt TableView searchbar

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtableview

Is there some UI widget for a searchbar in a table view? I mean, something like this (screenshot not a Qt widget, but showing how it should look like).

[image: jqGrid Seachbar]

I understand that [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) supports filtering. That is the model side. What I am looking for is a corresponding UI element on the view side. Or do I have to write it on my own?

Comment: I do not think this is possible with existing merhods. I'd create a custom `QWidget`-derived class for the header which contains a `QLabel` and `QLineedit` in a layout.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert a row in your `tableView` with the `model` you are using on it.

```
model->insertRow(0); //inserts row to the top
```

And then use `tableView->setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate);//make a lineEditDelegate`

Comment: Yes, I did have the same idea. The "issue" is that I always have to ignore that very first row from all operations like sorting, updates, etc. So all model operations have to accept an +1 row index.

Comment: Oh , okay i see.
You can make lineEdits and checkboxes individually and then anchor their positioning (their x's anchored to each other, and y anchored under the horizontalHeader of tableview). Set their height similar to `ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->height()`. Set their width similar to their corresponding columns. Set the height of `row(0)`equal to `verticalHeader()->height() x 2`. Then Lastly set the text/content of row(0) to be bottomjustified (I'm not sure how you call it but you got the idea, lol).